# Не работает фильтр мата, как исправить?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите, как исправить фильтр мата, не удаляются плохие слова.

Все варианты, что нашел в нете и перепробовал:

```
import aiogram
import logging
import math
import time
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import BoundFilter
from aiogram.utils import executor
from contextlib import suppress
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import (MessageToEditNotFound, MessageCantBeEdited, MessageCantBeDeleted,
MessageToDeleteNotFound)

bad_word = ["Мат", "мат2", "мат3"]

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text and message.text.lower() in bad_word and message.chat.id)
async def filter(message):
    await message.delete()

  
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text and message.text.lower() in bad_word and message.chat.id)
async def filter(message):
    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)


     
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter(message):
 if any([i for i in bad_word if i in message.text.lower()]):
     await message.delete()
 ban()



@dp.message_handler()
async def filter(message: types.Message):
    if bad_word in message.text:
     await message.delete() 
  

@dp.message_handler()
async def filter(message: types.Message):
    for word in bad_word:
        if word in message.text:
            await message.delete()
            break

@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):  
    for word in bad_word:
        if word in message.content.lower():
     await message.delete()         

@dp.message_handler()
async def filter(message: types.Message):
    if message.text.lower() in bad_word:
          await message.delete()
    

    

@dp.message_handler()
async def filter(message):
    for i in bad_word:
        if i in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
      
      
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter(message: types.Message):
  for i in bad_word:
    if mute in message.text:
        await message.delete()
    else:
        return


@dp.message_handler()
async def on_message(message):
    messageContent = message.content
    if any(word.lower() in messageContent.lower().replace(' ', '') for word in bad_word):
        await message.delete()



@dp.message_handler()
async def filter(message: types.Message):
    if any(word in message.text.lower() for word in bad_word):
       await message.forward(message.chat.id)
       await message.delete()
       time.sleep(1)
       print(message)
     


@dp.message_handler()
async def filter(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: return # если сообщение от бота - игнорируем
    for word in bad_word:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            try:
                await message.delete()
            except:
                pass
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, не ругайся матом')
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант для телеграм-бота с библиотекой `telebot`

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):

    words = ['мат', 'тоже мат', 'типо мата']

    phrase = message.text.lower()

    def distance(a, b): 
        n, m = len(a), len(b)
        if n > m:
        
            a, b = b, a
            n, m = m, n

        current_row = range(n + 1)
        for i in range(1, m + 1):
            previous_row, current_row = current_row, [i] + [0] * n
            for j in range(1, n + 1):
                add, delete, change = previous_row[j] + 1, current_row[j - 1] + 1, previous_row[j - 1]
                if a[j - 1] != b[i - 1]:
                    change += 1
                current_row[j] = min(add, delete, change)

        return current_row[n]

    d =   {'а' : ['а', 'a', '@'],
    'б' : ['б', '6', 'b'],
    'в' : ['в', 'b', 'v'],
    'г' : ['г', 'r', 'g'],
    'д' : ['д', 'd'],
    'е' : ['е', 'e'],
    'ё' : ['ё', 'e'],
    'ж' : ['ж', 'zh', '*'],
    'з' : ['з', '3', 'z'],
    'и' : ['и', 'u', 'i'],
    'й' : ['й', 'u', 'i', 'y'],
    'к' : ['к', 'k', 'i{', '|{'],
    'л' : ['л', 'l', 'ji'],
    'м' : ['м', 'm'],
    'н' : ['н', 'h', 'n'],
    'о' : ['о', 'o', '0'],
    'п' : ['п', 'n', 'p'],
    'р' : ['р', 'r', 'p'],
    'с' : ['с', 'c', 's'],
    'т' : ['т', 'm', 't'],
    'у' : ['у', 'y', 'u'],
    'ф' : ['ф', 'f'],
    'х' : ['х', 'x', 'h' , '}{'],
    'ц' : ['ц', 'c', 'u,'],
    'ч' : ['ч', 'ch'],
    'ш' : ['ш', 'sh'],
    'щ' : ['щ', 'sch'],
    'ь' : ['ь', 'b'],
    'ы' : ['ы', 'bi'],
    'ъ' : ['ъ'],
    'э' : ['э', 'e'],
    'ю' : ['ю', 'io'],
    'я' : ['я', 'ya']
    }

    for key, value in d.items():
        for letter in value:
            for phr in phrase:
                if letter == phr:
                    phrase = phrase.replace(phr, key)

    for word in words:
        for part in range(len(phrase)):
            fragment = phrase[part: part+len(word)]
            if distance(fragment, word) <= len(word)*0.15:
                bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id, )
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Дружище, [{} {}](tg://user?id={}), твоё сообщение было удалено из-за содержания в нём запрещённых слов! "
                        .format(message.from_user.first_name,
                                message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.id), disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Comment: А у него `aiogram`

Answer (score 0):

В своем боте я реализовал это так:

```
# Фильтр мата
for w in filte.fil.split('\n'):
    if w in message.text.lower().split(' '):
        await  message.answer('Старайся без матов говорить, пожалуйста :)')
```

`filte.fil.split('\n')` - тут я беру слова которые заранее заготовлены и разделены. Каждое слово с новой строки. Можно переделать как кому нравится.
Я подключил файл с переменной и беру все от туда.
Можно сразу списком брать, тогда не нужен будет `split('\n')`.

`if w in message.text.lower().split(' ')` - тут я разбиваю полученное сообщение на слова и сравниваю со списком выше.